# TRIGGER BEFORE DELETE, doesn't delete data in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on history of my database when a row is modify/delete.
My main table is "bati" and history table "bati_history", when a row is delete or modify, the trigger is suppose to insert into bati_history all the old data, then delete  in the main table (bati). But with my code, the row is insert into the history but not delete in the main table and I don't know why.

I'm on PostgreSQL 11.2 64-bit

The code :

Main table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bati(
    id_bati BIGSERIAL NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    code_bati VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    code_parcelle CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ...);
```

History table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bati_history(
    id_history BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    event CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    date_save_history TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    id_bati BIGINT NOT NULL,
    code_bati VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    code_parcelle CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        ...);
```

The function

```
CREATE FUNCTION archive_bati() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
  BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
      INSERT INTO bati_history (event,id_bati,code_bati,code_parcelle,...)
      VALUES ('DELETE',OLD.id_bati,OLD.code_bati,OLD.code_parcelle,OLD....);
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
      INSERT INTO bati_history (event,id_bati,code_bati,code_parcelle,...)
      VALUES ('UPDATE',OLD.id_bati,OLD.code_bati,OLD.code_parcelle,OLD....);
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

TRIGGERS:

```
CREATE TRIGGER bati_trigger_before_delete BEFORE DELETE
ON bati FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE archive_bati();

CREATE TRIGGER bati_trigger_before_update BEFORE UPDATE
ON bati FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE archive_bati();
```

When I try `DELETE FROM bati;`, I expect to copy every row in bati_history, then delete them from bati, but they are not delete from bati, and I have this output without error :

```
test=# INSERT INTO bati (id_bati,code_bati,code_parcelle,id_interne) VALUES (5,'CODEBATI001','CODEPARC001',02);
INSERT 0 1
test=# INSERT INTO bati (id_bati,code_bati,code_parcelle,id_interne) VALUES (6,'CODEBATI002','CODEPARC002',02);
INSERT 0 1
test=#  DELETE FROM bati;
DELETE 0
```

(sorry for my english I'm french)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a row, `NEW` is null. If the `before` trigger returns a null, it means the operation should be cancelled. You should then return `OLD` for deletions, and `NEW` for updates.

From the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> In the case of a before-trigger on DELETE, the returned value has no
>   direct effect, but it has to be nonnull to allow the trigger action to
>   proceed. Note that NEW is null in DELETE triggers, so returning that
>   is usually not sensible. The usual idiom in DELETE triggers is to
>   return OLD.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `if-else` branching to either return `NEW` OR `OLD` depending on the trigger operation. The variable `TG_OP` has a text type & could be used in the insert query directly.

So, the function definition becomes:

```
CREATE FUNCTION archive_bati() 
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO bati_history (event,id_bati,code_bati,code_parcelle) 
VALUES (TG_OP, OLD.id_bati, OLD.code_bati, OLD.code_parcelle);
IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' 
    THEN RETURN OLD; 
    ELSE RETURN NEW;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Also, it seems unnecessary to me to define two triggers when 1 will suffice:

```
CREATE TRIGGER bati_trigger_before_update BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE
ON bati FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE archive_bati();
```